# Is 3.5mm audio jack suitable for rotating connection?

Tags: audio, connector

I am designing a product where a removable accessory part should be connected while allowing rotation - boom microphone connected to a headset - you can plug and unplug and it should be possible to move with boom mic up and down as needed by the user.
The question is if a standard 3.5mm audio jack is a suitable connector for this purpose. I am afraid that it might lose contact after some time of use.
Would you accept using jack or recommend anything else?
Thanks

Comment: How many RPMs?  How many hours a day is it rotating?

Comment: Occasional twist, to raise mic away from mouth, probably fine. Continuous rotation, no way. Typical life connect/disconnect is 5000 cycles. I'd guess it can stand about the same number of rotations but there's no official spec.

Comment: @Justme English note: you *lend* the headphones to someone. They *borrow* it from you. In some languages they are the same word, but not in English.

Comment: Depends how the connector is rated, but unlikely. Even heaphone connectors being rotated while plugged into mobile phones look like it has been in a lathe if you lend it to someone that has tendency to wiggle it around if they have nothing else to fiddle with

Comment: Recommend you move the pivot to a mechanical joint with a flexible cable by it instead. The phono jack can plug in elsewhere with anti-rotation stops or tensile/compression mechanical supports to protect the plug against flex.

Comment: You could turn it, and again a few times. But to have continuous rotation would rapidly wear out the contacts.

Comment: A 3.5 mm jack isn't suitable for most anything.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=telephone+cord+detangler&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Ok, thanks for your opinions.About the number of rotations, it is difficult to say.The rough guess is that the user might move with boom mic 20 to 50 times per day - each movement would be 90° angle. In another post somebody recommended this: http://www.mercotac.com/html/205.html But then I worry about using exotic parts. There might be a serious issue with the supply chain if a manufacturer stops production. With jack, there is no such risk. Maybe I will go for heavy testing together with some mechanical precautions (support the axis of the jack to prevent any off-axis movements).

Answer (score 3):

Don't think so.  The forces, and the angles of the forces, are designed for medium-to-high contact pressure at a point, not what you want in a rotating contact.  Also, the plating probably will not hold up.  Contact lubricant, such as what is used in slip-ring connections and potentiometer wipers, will help.  But before I'd commit to it, I'd rig up a mechanical gadget to exercise the mechanism around the clock and get some data.

Comment: I'd say for a prototype or just something that you are messing around with, this would work fine.  If this is something that is going to need to be reliable over a long period of time, then no.  Use something that is specifically designed for this purpose.

Comment: So, use a clock to rotate the mechanism?

Comment: I used to work with a guy who loved this stuff. He would have used a pc back then, but an Arduino today with a stepper motor driven by a bounded random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

No. The jack is likely to wear rather quickly, and you might well get odd crackling noises and so on. Connections cause enough issues in audio gear anyway, this is asking a bit much. (And these components just aren't designed for this.)

Why not just let the cable do the work? Good quality multistrand cable absolutely IS intended for this. That's why it's cable, not solid wire.

Comment: I guess you mean to attach the boom mic by mechanical joint and connect it by a separate piece of cable with jack (or other) connector. Yes, that is a common approach. However, there are some requirements to avoid this due to aesthetic reasons. So right now I look for a solution where cable is not visible.

Comment: it must be possible to route the cable out of shot somehow? using a jack as a rotary joint is asking for problems.